# How to catch React propTypes warnings on server?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

While rendering React components on server all of the propTypes warning messages are falling to general output or `process.stdout`. For example, this is visible only in terminal or in general application log:

```
Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `title` was not specified in `Page`.
```

Is there any way to catch this warnings and transform them or pipe them into another direction? For instance, I want to separate application log and React (as template engine) log. How can I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like @m01, I wanted to make sure that any react errors (and in fact any js errors) cause my unit tests to fail, but I found a much simpler way to do it. At the top level of your tests, put this:

```
beforeAll(() => {
  console.error = (error) => {
    throw new Error(error);
  };
});
```

Comment: so it might be helpful if you post what your unit test looks like that uses this setup.  It doesn't tell me a whole lot just to show a beforeAll TBH.

Comment: @PositiveGuy sorry, I don't have the code any more for the project where I was using that. Also, it will differ depending on what testing framework you're using. Perhaps try looking up how to do global setup for your particular tool. I guess my main point is just to share the idea that you can mutate the global console object to throw an error.

Answer (score 3):

I needed the same thing, but for a different use case. I wanted to make sure that all my unit tests pass without any React warnings.

I use this in my test utils:

```
expectNoConsoleErrors: function() {
    var savedErrors;
    beforeEach(function () {
        savedErrors = [];
        spyOn(console, 'error').and.callFake(function () {
            var stack = new Error(_.map(arguments).join(' ')).stack;
            // if you need workarounds for come components, put them here
            savedErrors.push(stack);
        });
    });
    afterEach(function () {
        if (savedErrors.length > 0) {
            fail(savedErrors.join('\n'));
        }
    });
},
```

Then in `describe` block I put

```
myTestUtils.expectNoConsoleErrors()
```

And it works like a charm.

This is not very clean because it will also catch all other calls to `console.error`, but I don't want them during test anyway, so this seems ok for me.

Also, when I have some misbehaving component producing unnecessary warnings, like e.g. react-input-autosize I can ignore it using:

```
            // Workaround for https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/371
            if (_.contains(stack, 'react-input-autosize')) {
                return;
            }
```

Btw, note that before `v0.14`, React was using `console.warn` instead of `console.error` to produce these warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I tried looking into the React src how they print those output messages, but then I realized that it should only be printing those messages in development mode. If your node/iojs runtime is set to the "production" env, React should not even be doing those checks and that's what you want for a real app running. Those warnings are meant just for devs running locally.